# How can I regenerate a class url in doxygen?

Tags: doxygen

I am using doxygen to generate documentation for a program. Now I would like to link the generated documentation in another website/program (totally independent).

My idea is to generate a URL as same as doxygen generated, e.g. My class name is `Models.PMF.Phen.GenericPhase`, and doxygen generated url is `class_models_1_1_p_m_f_1_1_phen_1_1_generic_phase.html`. I don't understand why there are so many `underscore` and `1` in the url.

My questions are

1. Is it possible to change the style of doxygen generated URL, i.e. `class/Models/PMF/Phen/GenericPhase.html`?
2. Are there any patterns when doxygen generates a URL.

Thanks for any suggestion. Please let me know if my question is not clear.

Comment: The name mangling is use to be more system independent regarding names to be stored on disk (e.g. on windows no distinction between lower and upper case file names). The mapping algorithm can be found in the code (util.cpp routine convertNameToFile).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short story is: I think the URL that Doxygen generates is safe to use.

To answer the questions:
No, you can't get Doxygen to make the paths you want (but I agree that could be nice)

The underscores are Doxygen's way of getting the original name to be portable on any file system.  The `_1` is a replacement for the `.` character.  All capitals are replaced be lowercase preceded by `_`.  This mangling is pretty consistent so I think you should be able to use it safely.

There's a routine in util.cpp called `escapeCharsInString(...)` which does this conversion.  As I said, all capitals get changed to lowercase and preceded with underscore.  Various other characters get converted to _? (where ? is a number from 1 to 9 or 00 to 0C).  And lastly, the underscore itself is doubled if encountered. ("my_Function" ends up getting 3 underscores: `my___function`).

Below is a snippet of the source code for the various characters.  To be honest, I'm confused why you're getting `_1` for the `.`, because for my it converts to `_8`.  I'm in C, not C++; but even knowing that I've searched the source code and still not found an explanation.  Hence, I only say I "think" the URL is safe to use :)

```
  case '_': if (allowUnderscore) growBuf.addChar('_'); else growBuf.addStr("__"); break;
  case '-': growBuf.addChar('-');  break;
  case ':': growBuf.addStr("_1"); break;
  case '/': growBuf.addStr("_2"); break;
  case '<': growBuf.addStr("_3"); break;
  case '>': growBuf.addStr("_4"); break;
  case '*': growBuf.addStr("_5"); break;
  case '&': growBuf.addStr("_6"); break;
  case '|': growBuf.addStr("_7"); break;
  case '.': if (allowDots) growBuf.addChar('.'); else growBuf.addStr("_8"); break;
  case '!': growBuf.addStr("_9"); break;
  case ',': growBuf.addStr("_00"); break;
  case ' ': growBuf.addStr("_01"); break;
  case '{': growBuf.addStr("_02"); break;
  case '}': growBuf.addStr("_03"); break;
  case '?': growBuf.addStr("_04"); break;
  case '^': growBuf.addStr("_05"); break;
  case '%': growBuf.addStr("_06"); break;
  case '(': growBuf.addStr("_07"); break;
  case ')': growBuf.addStr("_08"); break;
  case '+': growBuf.addStr("_09"); break;
  case '=': growBuf.addStr("_0A"); break;
  case '$': growBuf.addStr("_0B"); break;
  case '\\': growBuf.addStr("_0C"); break;
```

Now going a step further, if the result name is > 128 characters, an MD5 encoding scheme is used which results in a file-name that looks like garbage.  It's basically an encryption of the original name, so again safe to use as long as your original name is always exactly the same (including arguments!).  See `convertNameToFile(...)` also in util.cpp.

Comment: BTW: I use C# and doxygen 1.8.9.1